# Существует ли общепринятый способ описать в документации сигнатуру фукции/метода?

Tags: java, c#, c++, bash, документация

Допустим есть некая функция, которая сама разбирает список аргументов

```
foo(...){

}
```

Сначала она ожидает агрумент `bar`, потом неограниченное число пар `baz` `quux`

```
foo(bar baz1 quux1 baz2 quux2 baz3 quux3)
```

Есть ли общепринятый способ описать аргументы функции? Что-то на подобие uml, но в виде текста. Например такое:

```
# Function foo
# foo(<bar> [<baz> <quux>]...)
foo(...){

}
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Doxygen (для C++)

Comment: как минимум в c# такое существует: [документирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc), при этом как в самом коде, так и в отдельном документе.

Comment: Хм, может я не понял суть вопроса, но вы же, наверное, знаете, что в `Java` существует `Javadoc`:  `
 /** Returns the highest bit that will be shifter out 
  * @param sumHi the higher word of the 128-bit value to be shifted
  * @param sumLo the lower word of the 128-bit value to be shifted
  * @param shift the distance the value will be shifted
  * @return 1, if the highest shifted-out bit is 1, 0 otherwise
  */
 private long highestShiftedOutBit(long sumHi, long sumLo int shift) 
 {...`
 Генерирует документацию в HTML и показывает всплывающую справку в IDE

Comment: @m.vokhm, вы все правильно поняли. Просто я не знаком с экосистемами всех языков в тегах, и хочу узнать как люди решают описанную задачу. Про `Javadoc` до этого момента не знал :)

Comment: Существует, но для каждого языка своё собственное

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылки на документацию по оформлению кода.

Конвенция для [java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) Раздел 5.2

Стандарты [С++](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), [PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) и [ISO 17](https://www.iso.org/committee/45202.html)

[C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/ecma-c-common-language-infrastructure-standards/) и [XML-стандарт](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/codedoc)

Comment: За жаву и шарп спасибо. А вот на счет С++, я почти на 100% уверен что в стандарте про оформление код ни слова.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Я искал по запросу documentation C++ code, выдало сторонние сайты, подумал, что лучше будет  сослаться на сайты серьезных компании.